# ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO) on Windows

Tags: mysql, windows-10

when i want start mysql in windwos cmd i got this error
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
what can i do?

```
mysql -u root -p

ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
```

Comment: did you ever set a root password?

Comment: no i havnot password

Comment: then you don't need the -p tag `-p` specifies `with password`, just run `mysql -uroot`

Answer (score 0):

You can [reset your root password](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/resetting-permissions.html). Have in mind that it is not advisable to use root without password.

Comment: i have not password

Answer (score 0):

install MYSQL again and define pass for root and define a user
and after instalation MYSQL work on cmd whit

```
cd c:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\bin>
```

then

```
mysql -u myusername -p
```

then ask my pass and enter the password of this user name(not root password) and it work

other way for run MYSQL is start menu

in **start menu** find folder that named **MySQL** and expand it
and run **MySQL command line client**

Answer (score 0):

you can find your password by

```
#  cat /var/log/mysqld.log  | grep password
```

Comment: Add more info on why this is an asnwer.

Answer (score 0):

These errors sometimes due to DNS problem. To fix it, execute `mysqladmin flush-hosts` to reset the internal DNS host cache.